# Анимация SVG: сначала строк, затем заполнение цветом

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация

Необходимо добиться следующего эффекта: http://gph.is/2iZZ3Hw -
рисования контуров и затем заполнение цветом.
Для определения общей длины путей может понадобиться `JS`.

*Ниже код*

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;stroke:#FEC558;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256;}
    .st1{fill:#FFC656;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z"/>
    <g>
        <polygon class="st1" points="14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7 
    32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2   "/>
        <polygon class="st1" points="19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 
    15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7     "/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Animate SVG with CSS: first the stroke, then the fill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47342089/7394871) от участника  [@Cristian C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8955039/cristian-c).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47342089/7394871

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" >
<style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
     fill:none;
     stroke:#FEC558;
     stroke-width:0.5;
     }
    .st1{fill:#FFC656;}
</style>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
         
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#33363D"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5B5D5A"/>
</lineargradient>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>

<path id="circle" class="st0" stroke-dashoffset="138" stroke-dasharray="138" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z">
<animate id="an_circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="138;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</path>
    <g stroke-width="0.5">
       <path id="trap" class="st1" stroke-dashoffset="60" stroke-dasharray="60" style="fill:none; stroke:#FEC558;" d="M14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7  32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2z">
        <animate id="an_trap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="60;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate id="fill_trap" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="an_circle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
        <path id="triangle" class="st1" stroke-dashoffset="35" stroke-dasharray="35" style="fill:none; stroke:#FEC558;"  d="M19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7">
        
        <animate id="an_triangle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_trap.end" values="35;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
          <animate id="fill_triangle" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="fill_trap.end-0.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Из [примера](http://gph.is/2iZZ3Hw) видно, что нужно анимировать строки трёх объектов логотипа: круга, трапеции и треугольника, затем заполнить цветом трапецию и треугольник.

Для анимации строк определяем их длину с помощью JS

```
<script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#circle');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("path length - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

**Найденная длина для:**

окружности - 138px

трапеции - 60px

треугольника - 35px

- Команды для анимации рисования строк

```
<animate id="an_circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="138;0" 
     dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
```

```
  <animate id="an_trap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="60;0" 
      dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

```
  <animate id="an_triangle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
    begin="an_trap.end" values="35;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

- Анимация рисования треугольника начнется, когда закончится анимация
  рисования трапеции

`begin="an_trap.end"`

- Анимация закрашивания трапеции начнется, когда закончится анимация
  рисования окружности

```
    <animate id="fill_trap" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  
    begin="an_circle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

- Анимация заполнение цветом треугольника начнется, когда закончится
  анимация заполнения цветом трапеции

```
<animate id="fill_triangle" attributeName="fill"
   values="#33363D;#FEC558"  
     begin="fill_trap.end-0.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

**UPD**

Поддержка всеми современными браузерами кроме IE https://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20smil

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47349649/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Comment: у меня к тебе будет просьба.. если можно, я завтра реализую один пример на чистом css, подскажешь, как на svg переделать?  как сделаю отпишусь тут в коменте...  будет время глянешь?  я лучше вникаю на примерах

Comment: ок ок))))))))))

Comment: @Alexandr_T **Здравствуйте!** Ваше решение кажется неплохим, но нет поддержки IE-11. При этом нет и альтернативы для данного браузера, т.е. там просто черный квадрат. Я должно быть не знаю ни одного проекта, где бы не требовалась поддержка IE-11, Win-7 это IE-11, и ее еще многие используют. Мне вариант с решением, которое неприменимо на практике, не кажется решением. Если вы предлагаете для IE-10/11 делать альтернативу, которая будет отображаться именно там, тогда, считаю, это нужно отразить в коде. Также стоит написать поддержку браузерами вашего решения. Всего вам доброго!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov IE8-IE11, Edge не поддерживает анимацию svg из принципа и как сказал их главный менеджер поддерживать не будет никогда. https://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20smil Только хаки и js  библиотеки типа рафаэль и snap.js от Дмитрия Барановского справляются с этим.

Comment: @Alexandr_T Я ведь предложил сделать альтернативу для IE-11, чтобы там показывалось что-то вместо черного квадрата. Теперь я вижу, это еще и в Edge не поддерживается. Согласны вы в том, что в таком виде как у вас, это неприменимо на практике?

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov вы не мечтаете пойти работать главным менеджером Microsoft? У них такая же позиция. Планировал завтра и без ваших советов написать то же самое на CSS, но код будет раза в 4 больше. И к вашему сведению CSS анимация не может и половину сделать, того что реализуется в smill SVG легко и просто.

Comment: @Alexandr_T Простите, если обидел своими словами. Я сам верстальщик, и вот, мое мнение, с такой поддержкой, это неприменимо на практике в коммерческих проектах. Только это я хотел написать. Второе, я написал, что тогда можно делать отдельную версию для IE, когда мы эту скрываем и показываем например просто готовую картинку в IE, но без анимации. Но в таком виде как сейчас это не стоит оставлять. Еще раз приношу извинения, если мои слова были непонятны/грубы.

Answer (score 4):

### CSS решение

Анимация рисования контуров фигур реализуется в этом варианте с помощью правил CSS.
Точно также необходимо определить длину пути для каждой фигуры и использовать её для анимации изменения атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` от максимальной значения до нуля.

*Для круга*

```
.circle {
    fill:none;
    stroke:#FEC558;
    stroke-dashoffset:138.5;
    stroke-dasharray:138.5;
    animation: circle_stroke 2s ease-in forwards;
        } 
    
    @keyframes circle_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 138.5;
    }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

Точно также необходимо повторить для трапеции и треугольника.

Но для этих фигур необходимо добавить ещё анимацию заполнения цветом.
Правило CSS для совместной анимации будет написано так:

```
.trap {
    stroke-dashoffset:60;
    stroke-dasharray:60;
        animation:trap_stroke 2s ease-in-out forwards,  trap_fill  ease-in 3s forwards;
    
    }
    
    @keyframes trap_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60.5;
    }
          
      100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }  
    
    @keyframes trap_fill {
    0% {
    fill: none;
    }
          
      100% {
    fill: #FEC558;
      }
    }
```

*Код для всей анимации:*

```css
 .trap, .triangle {
   stroke:#FEC558;
   stroke-width:0.5;
    fill:none;
   }
    
    .circle {
    fill:none;
    stroke:#FEC558;
    stroke-dashoffset:138.5;
    stroke-dasharray:138.5;
    animation: circle_stroke 2s ease-in forwards;
        } 
    
    @keyframes circle_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 138.5;
    }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    

    
    
    .trap {
    stroke-dashoffset:60;
    stroke-dasharray:60;
        animation:trap_stroke 2s ease-in-out forwards,  trap_fill  ease-in 3s forwards;
    
    }
    
    @keyframes trap_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60.5;
    }
          
      100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }  
    
    @keyframes trap_fill {
    0% {
    fill: none;
    }
          
      100% {
    fill: #FEC558;
      }
    }  


    .triangle {
    stroke-dashoffset:35.5;
    stroke-dasharray:35.5;
    
    animation: triangle_stroke 1s ease-in-out forwards, triangle_fill 3.5s ease-in forwards;
    }  
    
    @keyframes triangle_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35.5;
    }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }  
    
    @keyframes triangle_fill {
    0% {
    fill: none;
    }
    100% {
    fill: #FEC558;;
      }
    }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">  

<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
         
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#33363D"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5B5D5A"/>
</lineargradient>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>

<path class="circle" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z"/>

    
       <path class="trap"    d="M14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7  32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2z" />
          
        <path class="triangle"   d="M19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7"/>
    

</svg>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q3a1kzyu/)

Работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме **IE**

"[IE10 and IE11 do not support CSS keyframe blocks inside media queries](https://caniuse.com/#search=animation)."
(см. вкладку Known Issues  )

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47376337/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>