# SVG / SMIL Последователый вызов двух анимаций

Tags: html, css3, svg, анимация, smil

Подскажите, как при работе со `SMIL` анимацией в `SVG` добиться эффекта последовательного выполнения двух анимаций.

Приведу пример

```css
#letters {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 840px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.letters_path {
  fill: #40CAF4;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #091C52;
}
```

```html
<svg id="letters" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 550">
   <path id="path_V" class="letters_path"
                                  stroke-dasharray="578.8"
                                  d="M236.3,145.9h0.3c16.7,0,29.5,3.3,38.2,10c2.3,1.8,3.5,3.1,3.5,4l-0.2,0.2l-7.9-3.9v0.2c8.9,11,13.4,17.1,13.4,18.2c0,1.6-3.7,7.9-11,18.7c-8.2,15.2-16.3,28.3-24.2,39.2l-26,31.2H222l0.2-6.1c-1.2-9.9-2.2-20.3-3.1-31.4c-0.2-0.1-0.6-16.1-0.6-16.1c-1.2-3.3-1.8-5.4-1.8-6.3c1.2-1.2,2.1-1.8,2.8-1.8c0-1-1.5-2.9-4.6-5.7c0.6-0.8,1.6-8.1,3.2-21.9c0-1.5-3.8-5.5-3.8-5.5c0.6-0.2,1.3-0.3,2.2-0.3c0,0-4.6-5.2-4.9-5.2v-0.2c0-0.4,3.6-1,10.9-1.8l-2.4-2.4v-0.3h0.2c2,0,6.2,2.2,12.4,6.6c1.5,0.8,2.5,1.2,3.1,1.2l-6.1-9.9c0,0,10.3,11.1,10.3,12.7v6.7h-0.2c-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.6-2-0.6h-3v0.2c0,0.4,0.7,1.9,2.1,4.5l0.3,1c-0.3,0.6-0.6,1-0.8,1h-0.2c-0.6,0-1.6-0.6-2.8-1.8v0.3l0.8,4.2c-0.7,2.3-1.5,8.8-2.4,19.5c-0.9,5.2-2.5,18-4.8,38.6c0.7,0,13.7-23.9,16.7-29.3h-1.5v-0.3c1.6-2,3.3-5.6,4.9-10.8c7-16.2,10.7-25,11-26.4c0.7-4.9,1.3-8,1.8-9.3c-2.4-1.1-3.8-2-4.2-2.7l0.2-0.3h0.3l9,0.6c0-1.2-2.4-3.5-7.1-6.7c-2.3-2.3-9.6-6.1-21.9-11.4v-0.4L236.3,145.9L236.3,145.9z">
                                <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="578.8;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" begin=letters.click
                                         calcMode="linear"/>
                                         </path>                     
 
 </svg>
```

Идея следующая -> Изначально экран пустой.
 По клику в области SVG сначало отрабатывает анимация отрисовки пути для буквы, когда она закончилась происходит закрашивание фона, от `opacity:0` до `fill: #40CAF4;` (Ну или как-то через rgba);

1) Как добиться, чтобы  изначально всё было пустым?
2) Как произвести одну анимацию над `stroke-dashoffset` а затем над `fill` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для последовательного выполнения нескольких анимаций необходимо каждой анимации присвоить `ID`
Допустим анимации с прорисовкой контура буквы с помощью `stroke-dashoffset` присваиваете

```
<animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" stroke-dashoffset="578" stroke-dasharray="578" values="578.8;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" begin=letters.click                                          calcMode="linear"/>
```

для второй команды анимации - заполнение цветом присваиваете `<animate id="an2"`

```css
#letters {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 840px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.letters_path {
  fill: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #091C52;
}
```

```html
<svg id="letters" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 550">
 <path id="path_V" class="letters_path"  stroke-dasharray="578.8" stroke-dashoffset=578.8
                                  d="M236.3,145.9h0.3c16.7,0,29.5,3.3,38.2,10c2.3,1.8,3.5,3.1,3.5,4l-0.2,0.2l-7.9-3.9v0.2c8.9,11,13.4,17.1,13.4,18.2c0,1.6-3.7,7.9-11,18.7c-8.2,15.2-16.3,28.3-24.2,39.2l-26,31.2H222l0.2-6.1c-1.2-9.9-2.2-20.3-3.1-31.4c-0.2-0.1-0.6-16.1-0.6-16.1c-1.2-3.3-1.8-5.4-1.8-6.3c1.2-1.2,2.1-1.8,2.8-1.8c0-1-1.5-2.9-4.6-5.7c0.6-0.8,1.6-8.1,3.2-21.9c0-1.5-3.8-5.5-3.8-5.5c0.6-0.2,1.3-0.3,2.2-0.3c0,0-4.6-5.2-4.9-5.2v-0.2c0-0.4,3.6-1,10.9-1.8l-2.4-2.4v-0.3h0.2c2,0,6.2,2.2,12.4,6.6c1.5,0.8,2.5,1.2,3.1,1.2l-6.1-9.9c0,0,10.3,11.1,10.3,12.7v6.7h-0.2c-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.6-2-0.6h-3v0.2c0,0.4,0.7,1.9,2.1,4.5l0.3,1c-0.3,0.6-0.6,1-0.8,1h-0.2c-0.6,0-1.6-0.6-2.8-1.8v0.3l0.8,4.2c-0.7,2.3-1.5,8.8-2.4,19.5c-0.9,5.2-2.5,18-4.8,38.6c0.7,0,13.7-23.9,16.7-29.3h-1.5v-0.3c1.6-2,3.3-5.6,4.9-10.8c7-16.2,10.7-25,11-26.4c0.7-4.9,1.3-8,1.8-9.3c-2.4-1.1-3.8-2-4.2-2.7l0.2-0.3h0.3l9,0.6c0-1.2-2.4-3.5-7.1-6.7c-2.3-2.3-9.6-6.1-21.9-11.4v-0.4L236.3,145.9L236.3,145.9z">
<animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="578.8;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" begin=letters.click /> 
<animate id="an2" attributeName="fill" values="white;#40CAF4" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="an1.end"                                    />
                                         </path>                     
 
 </svg>
```

Условие начала второй анимации по окончанию первой анимации - `begin=an1.end`

Comment: Спасибо, а как добиться что б изначально экран выглядел пустым ? - Только после срабатывания события клик прорисовывать stroke-dashoffset ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 нужно добавить stroke-dashoffset="578" stroke-dasharray="578" изменил код в сниппете. Проверить не могу, так как на моем компе остался только IE11, а он не работает с анимацией stroke-dashoffset

Comment: @BlackStar1991 вот ещё посмотри топик, там более подробные объяснения и пример посложнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746113/28748